# Using Javascript to dynamically display a number

Tags: javascript

This code should generate a page that displays a random number. Why doesn't it work?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = generateRandomNumber();
function generateRandomNumber()
{
    var n = 25;
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
    document.getElementById("randomNumber").value = number;
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Random number generated = <h1 id="randomNumber"></h1>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check my answer.. updated as per your updated question.

Comment: uploaded snapshot for your reference.. check it out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make use of `window.onload`. try this

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
             var n = 25;
             var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
             document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = number;
        };
     </script>
 </head>
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yyAf8/

**EDIT as per updated question:**

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = generateRandomNumber;
     function generateRandomNumber(){
         var n = 25;
         var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
         document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = number;
        }
  </script>
</head>
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yyAf8/1/

**uploading snapshot on demand by OP:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work when the code is put in an html file. Can you show what the whole code looks like?

Comment: uploaded snapshot in the answer.

Comment: It wasn't working because I was setting value and not innerHTML.

Answer (score 3):

Because in your script you use an element that is not defined yet. Put the script after the element.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/upihez/2

Comment: OK that worked, but is there a way I can still keep the javascript code in in the head? Can I use onload to do this?

Comment: I put it in a function and updated the code in my question. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Because this time `generateRandomNumber` doesn't exist! Do this: `window.onload = function() {...}`

Comment: That didn't work. Can you show what my code looks like when it's fixed?